# Throttling an Ajax progress bar

Tags: jquery, ajax

The following script below updates a progress bar by making an ajax request twice per second (using setInterval with a 500 ms timeout). I've added an isBusy flag so as to NOT make the ajax request if a pre-existing request has not yet received a response. But it doesn't work. Of course when I comment out line 19, which is where I am setting the flag to  busy waiting on response, all works ok. What am I doing wrong? How do I make it to that only 1 ajax request at a time is "alive" and waiting on a response?

```
01 var exportHandler = {
02 
03     handlerUrl: '',
04     intervalId: 0,
05     isBusy: 0,
06 
07     start: function () {        
08 
09         // do some set up work
10 
11         exportHandler.isBusy = 0; // init flag to not busy, not waiting on resp
12 
13         exportHandler.intervalId = setInterval(function () {
14 
15             if (exportHandler.isBusy == 1) {
16                 return; // response to previous request not yet rcvd
17             }
18 
19             exportHandler.isBusy = 1; // set flag to busy waiting on response
20 
21             exportHandler.getProgress();
22         }, 500);
23     },
24 
25     cancel: function () {
26         exportHandler.isBusy = 1;  // not sure if I need this here???
27 
28         if (exportHandler.intervalId != 0) {
29             clearInterval(exportHandler.intervalId);
30         }
31 
32         exportHandler.intervalId = 0;
33         event.preventDefault();
34         return false;
35     },
36 
37     getProgress: function () {
38 
39         $.ajax({
40             url: exportHandler.handlerUrl,
41             dataType: 'json',
42             async: true,
43             data: ...,
44 
45             error: function (o, st, err) {
46                 exportHandler.isBusy = 0; // err occured so reset flag to not busy waiting on response
47                 
48                 // handle error
49             },
50 
51             success: function (job) {
52                 exportHandler.isBusy = 0; // response rcvd so reset flag to not busy waiting on response
53 
54                 showProgress(job, exportHandler);
55 
56                 if (job.JobComplete) {
57                     jobsDone(exportHandler.intervalId, 'export');
58                 }
59             }
60         });
61     }
62 
63 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generaly a bad practice to execute an ajax call inside an interval. You could try this:

```
var ajaxCall = function(ajaxData) {
  // Start loader
  setLoader('start');
  $.ajax({
     url: '..',
     data: ajaxData,
     success: function(data) {
       // Stop loader
       setLoader('stop');
       // Do some actions ...
       // Call this function after 500ms as soon as the function returns it's data
       setInterval(function() {

         ajaxCall(data);
       }, 500);
     }
  });
}

// Create a function that handles loader state
var setLoader = function(mode) {
  if (mode && mode.length > 0) {
    switch (mode) {
      case 'start':
        // Start loader
        break;
      case 'stop':
        // Stop loader
        break;
    }
  }
}

// Call ajaxCall function for the first time
ajaxCall({ some: 'data' });
```